# How was the lab in Æon Flux hidden?

Tags: cloaking, aeon-flux

At some point in the Æon Flux movie, the titular heroine discovers what seems like a library. By means of a device, the library environment changes into a lab secretly used by Trevor Goodchild to find a cure for the infertility that the population (unknowingly) suffers from.

Later on, said room is revisited during a physical struggle with a (at the time) villain, Freya. The environment switches forth and back several times, and the impression is created that only the currently visible objects can do harm to the struggling protagonists. A clip showing some of this struggle is currently available on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ow9U0uWCfDY).

**How was that cloaking of the lab implemented in-universe?**

- Was the library "simply" a hologram? But then, why the frequent switching of scenery during the struggle?
- Were the characters actually teleported in some way? That doesn't seem consistent with the apparent total absence of teleportation technology in the rest of the movie.
- Was one of the two environments (presumably the lab) just a virtual reality? But if so, how could Trevor Goodchild be certain that his experiments would yield accurate results (given that the results, or any observations, would be only a simulation)?

Answer (score 6):

This entire sequence was taken pretty much directly from the original Aeon Flux TV show episode [Utopia or Deuteranopia?](http://aeonflux.wikia.com/wiki/Utopia_or_Deuteranopia%3F).

There's no specific scientific explanation offered in either the episode or the film other than that it appears to be some kind of pocket dimension or folded space that the special suspenders (in the film some kind of genetically engineered squid) allows you to enter by [vibrating at a specific frequency](https://vimeo.com/114724394).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't remember in the movie that they were wearing the vibrio suits though (and I'm not going to rewatch that travesty to find out)

Answer (score -1):

The vibration effect was made to imply that the rooms were occupying the same space, just vibrating at different frequencies. The standard model of quantum mechanics posits matter waves that essentially become irrelevant at larger scales. But many sci-fi franchises have used the matter wave explanation for parallel realities that exist in the same space but simply are inaccessible to each other because they vibrate at different frequencies. Most recently I can think of the Supergirl tv series just before it became part of the Arrowverse. Season 1 Episode 18 has the Flash show up in Supergirl's universe and when he is explaining the multiverse to team Supergirl, he uses the above explanation. One can only think that the technology in Bregna in late 2415, as the AEON FLUX film depicts, has reached the point where hiding structures in vibrationally different spaces is just one more on the long list of Clarke-tech which to us is indistinguishable from magic.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This makes sense as a hypothesis, and seems to explain the effect that's shown, but do you have any evidence that this is what was intended by the creators?